# Save order and placement of movieclips to a file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an application that allows the user to create a custom banner. The app allows the user to add uploaded images (using FileReference) to the banner as well as adding images that are built-in to the application and can be selected within the app. Most of the elements that can be added to the banner are movieclips or textfields.

What I want to do is have a 'Save Design' button that saves the current configuration that the user has set so that if they close and reopen the app they can click the 'Load Design' button and it will load in their previously made design with the right properties (Colours, image position etc.)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to store the information in a [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).

The images that are loaded using `FileReference` can each be stored as a `ByteArray`. Then, when they're retrieved, you can use [`Loader.loadBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29) to reload the images.

Here's a quick example which is in no way complete, but it should get you started in the right direction:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savedBanner");

function save():void
{
    so.data.objects = [];
    // loop over all of your display objects and save their information/position
    for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
    {
        var displayObject:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
        var savedObject:Object = {};
        savedObject.className = getQualifiedClassName(displayObject);
        savedObject.x = displayObject.x;
        savedObject.y = displayObject.y;
        savedObject.rotation = displayObject.rotation;
        savedObject.scaleX = displayObject.scaleX;
        savedObject.scaleY = displayObject.scaleY;
        // store any other pertinent data
        so.data.objects.push(savedObject);
    }
    so.flush();
}

function load():void {
    for each(var savedObject:Object in so.data.objects)
    {
        var newObject:DisplayObject = new (getDefinitionByName(savedObject.className) as Class)();
        newObject.x = savedObject.x;
        newObject.y = savedObject.y;
        newObject.rotation = savedObject.rotation;
        newObject.scaleX = savedObject.scaleX;
        newObject.scaleY = savedObject.scaleY;
        addChild(newObject);
    }
}
```